# Vim Devicons Icon glitch on MacVim and Terminal Vim

Tags: macos, github, vim, fonts, macvim

As I was setting up my **~/.vimrc**, I installed **Plugin 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'** (https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons) and **Plugin 'preservim/nerdtree'** (https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree) - I ran into a problem. I couldn't see the desired Python file icons for any of my Python (.py) files in Nerd Tree window in Terminal Vim and Mac Vim.

The solution to this problem is rather simple as someone did figured it out already. (https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons/issues/198)
I am sharing this information on StackOverflow community for a quicker reference.

Comment: Why the negative score? Am I doing something wrong here? Please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: The whole thing is pointless as all the information is readily available in two interlinked READMEs. Use Twitter instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For seeing the file type specific icons in a File browser like Nerd Tree in Vim,

*first please install -* **NERD FONT**

(https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts#font-installation)

by using the command:

`brew tap homebrew/cask-fonts`

`brew install --cask font-hack-nerd-font`

Final step -

*For Terminal Vim: (Mac OS)*

Change Terminal font to **Hack Nerd Font**

*For Mac Vim: (GUI Vim)*

Add this line to your **vimrc** file -

**set guifont=hack_nerd_font:h21**

(h21 sets the font size - change it any value based on your preference)
(save the changes to the vimrc file with command **:wq**)